# Files copied from raw folder can't be get opened

Tags: android, excel

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(rawid);
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(FILE_DIRECTORY_PATH + "/" + fileName );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;

    try {
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
         try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

With the help of above code I copied some .xls file on the sdcard but when I try to open file using following code it gives error as "This document cannot be opened" or "File format not supported" but it I go to file explorer and try to open file it get open without error.

```
Uri path = Uri.parse(FILE_DIRECTORY_PATH + "/abc.xls");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(BluTest.this, "No Application Available to View Excel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: do you actually have something installed to manage xls file? Code looks good. Do you get any exception? After writing can you check ti file size? You close two times in and out. Remove the one after the flush() call

Comment: Yes I have two applications and those two application opens copied files if i go through File explorer..Error is something like not a supported document format...

Comment: then you kwon why it is not working.

Comment: But same file gets opened when I go through File explorer?? Why ??

Comment: sorry I misunderstood what you wrote. If the  ActivityNotFoundException is thrown than probably "application/vnd.ms-excel" is wrong, or the file does not exists. Try creating a file from FILE_DIRECTORY_PATH + "/abc.xls" and check what  File.exits(), returns

Comment: Checked File present...

Comment: What is the value of FILE_DIRECTORY_PATH and fileName? Just want to confirm that you are not adding extra slash.

Comment: That is path of folder I hard coded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputStream in = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(FILE_DIRECTORY_PATH + "/" + fileName );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;

    try {
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
         try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

To open a file

```
    File temp = new File(GlobalValues.CSV_FILE_DIRECTORY_PATH
            + fileName);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+temp.getAbsolutePath() ), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Application Available to View Excel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

So the changes are as follows

1. I put files in asset folder.
2. Instead of FileOutputStream we need to use OutputStream.
3. Change in getting file path.